# Regex to find a unique pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, regular-language, nsregularexpression

Hi I have tried getting a specific pattern using regex but did not succeed. I have the following string and would like to know if it can be done with regex:

```
query pets {
  breed(some params lorem ipsum) {
    totalDogs
    dogs {
      adopted(some params) {
        has {
          owner
          ownerId
          petId
        }
      }
      ownerName
      ownerId
      Id
    }
  }
}
```

My final goal is to get the following string from the above string of data: `adopted.has[*].ownerId`

The `[*]` in `adopted.has[*].ownerId` is to be hardcoded in the regex pattern or any other way if possible.

Comment: In general, you may need a parser for this type of requirement.

Comment: What parser can I use considering the above query is a string ?

Comment: You may try writing your own parser, or, that failing, look into using a library like ANTLR.  The regex solution you accepted may be OK, provided that there are no edge cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, `adopted`, `has` and `ownerId` are variables?
If so - see this: https://regex101.com/r/c7TEKR/1

`/\s+(.+)\(.+\).+\s+(.+?)\s+.+\s+.+\s+(.+)/g` => `$1.$2[*].$3`

Comment: Hey Thanks I appreciate your help. Can you please help in the following string as my query(string) will have params and an extra variable. The above expression will not work on the following: 

https://regex101.com/r/fHwmae/1

The goal is to get: ```adopted.has[*].ownerId```

Comment: Hi can yon please help ^ ?

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/TS17nb/1
But I don't understand your use-case

Comment: Hey thanks I appreciate. Just last question. Is it possible to remove everything before a string. For example in the following code: https://regex101.com/r/d1tLon/1
Can you please write a expression which would remove everything before ```dogs``` and just have this string: https://regex101.com/r/L7TCwj/1 

also let me know if I can buy you a coffee :)

Comment: Thanks for your offer, but simply upvoting and/or accepting my answer will do. I just don't understand your problem, like what is variable and what is static. Anyway, might help: https://regex101.com/r/6lsyf3/1

Comment: Thank You I got what I needed. Thanks for helping out !

Comment: The only requirement was to get the string: ```adopted.has[*].ownerId``` from the following code: 
https://regex101.com/r/fHwmae/1